# PyCharm: how to use an open source project in my project

Tags: pycharm

I want to build a simple tool that uses functions from an open source project from GitHub, SourceForge, etc. (e.g., a project such as https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi/).

I searched the documentation but could not find the right way to do this. (I assume I need to point PyCharm at the source somehow and "import")

I am utterly new to PyCharm and Python in general. This is just a test project. I am running PyCharm Pro 4.5 on OS X 10.10.3. PyCharm is up and running and just need to get to these functions.

Thanks so much.

Comment: it would help a lot if you told us which library from sourceforge you want to use

Comment: I'm considering several -- and I've just eliminated the source forge one. My first choice at the moment is at:  http://old.mxm.dk/products/public/pythonmidi/index.html. GPL license. Another choice that would work is at https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi/ (MIT license)

Comment: I'm updating the question above to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install this library from PyCharm via Settings | Project | Project Interpreter | Available Packages. AFAIK, the library is called [midi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/midi).

Alternatively, you can install "midi" using the "pip" command line tool.

Answer (score 0):

An open source project should have a license. So, you just need to check which license is used by the open source project you want to use and following the required terms.

Check licenses [here](http://choosealicense.com/).

Comment: It's GPL. This is also a fair-use test program.

Answer (score 0):

From what you write it seems as if you want to install the library from sourceforge, then make a new project with some python module that imports that library and uses its functions...

If the library you want to use is properly listed on http://pypi.python.org, you can just create a new python module and just write `import library_i_want_to_use`. If `library_i_want_to_use` is installed on your system and pycharm finds it, you can just go ahead. Otherwise pycharm will complain that it can't find the library and provide a quickfix to install the library for you.

[image: example for installing the <code>cachetools</code> library]

If the library isn't properly listed as python library, you have to install it manually, probably according to the README that it should provide.

Comment: The README doesn't provide any such information. I suppose that's what I'm asking: how do I "install" it?

Comment: well, it says `python setup.py install`... so you download the source, extract it, go into the directory and run that or you can try `pip install python-midi`

Comment: btw: if that fails due to permissions, you probably need to run it as root with `sudo python setup.py install` or `sudo pip install python-midi`